# SonarQube Issue with FindBugs plugin

Tags: maven, sonarqube, findbugs

The client I work for is willing to add the Findbugs plugin to the current SonarQube instance in order to apply the integrated security rules. The plugin was in fact already installed but gave the following error:

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar
>   (default) on project tests-v1: Can not execute Findbugs

Can someone please comment on what additional config (judging by the error - something missing in Maven?) we need to apply in order to implement the Findbugs plugin successfully?

Comment: Please add information about server version, list of the installed plugins and the whole stack trace.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the delay in my response - turns out it is/was a known issue and they just released a fix, details can be found here: https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/issues/218